# C# Smart Text and Word Extraction

Tags: c#

Not too familiar with stuff like Ngrams etc but have been playing around with it.

What would the best way to go about extracting ngrams or a set of words from a string that are "relevant" without strings that dont really mean anything.

Input example: A Course in Muscle-Testing and Energy Healing

output would be: Muscle-Testing, Energy Healing

Another Input example: Workout Routine To Increase VERTICAL Jump

output would be: Workout Routine, Increase Vertical Jump

Messed around with stopwords etc but obviously thats very flawed.

Any thoughts??